# How to map a mapped const in another const React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok so say I have 3 arrays like so:

```
import React from 'react';

const hello = ['hello', 'hi', 'sup'];
const bye = ['bye', 'goodbye', 'see ya'];
const names = ['john', 'bob', 'jill'];
```

Then let's say that I want to map each array like so:

```
const helloWorld = hello.map(helloCode => {
  return (
    <div>{helloCode}</div>
  );
});

const goodBye = bye.map(byeCode => {
  return (
    <div>{byeCode}</div>
  );
});

const allNames = names.map(nameCode => {
  return (
    <div>{nameCode}</div>
  );
});
```

Now suppose that I want to take all three of those mapped functions and map them like so:

```
const all = [helloWorld, byeWorld, allNames];

const Everything = all.map(allCode => {
    return (
        <div>{allCode}</div>
    );
});
```

How would I go about doing that because this way doesn't seem to work. I really just need answers in react. Anyways if anyone can help me figure this out it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your `all` is an array of arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the array like this

```
const all = [helloWorld, byeWorld, allNames];
const flattenedArray = [].concat.apply([], all)
// or use array destructuring
// const flattenedArray = [...helloWorld, ...byeWorld, ...allNames]
const Everything = flattenedArray.map(allCode => {
    return (
        <div>{allCode}</div>
    );
});
```

Comment: I am getting output that is in a vertical line, but instead I need each array to have its output be like this: hello hi sup. but it just lists every item as if they were each in their own separate divs

Comment: @DeadOnBullseye This will output as you described. i.e. "hello hi sup bye goodbye see ya".

Answer (score 0):

Your `all` is an array of arrays. To convert it to an array, spread the inner arrays

```
const all = [...helloWorld, ...byeWorld, ...allNames]; //all  is now an array

const Everything = all.map(allCode => {
    return (
        <div>{allCode}</div>
    );
});
```